# JSP not returing result with drop down menu

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

having a issues with getting the result of a query based on the drop down select, for some reason its not returning anything when trying to post it on to the jsp.

here is my what code looks like

here is my index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="Test">
    <h3>Get today's feed event</h3>
    <p>
        <select name="colour" size="1" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse">
            <option value="light">Runningball</option>
            <option value="amber">Enetpulse</option>
            <option value="DonBest">DonBest</option>
            <option value="BetRadar">Betradar</option>

        </select>
        </p>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
</form>
```

and here is my logic

```
public List<String> getColours(String colour) {


    List<String> colours = new ArrayList<String>();
     if(colour.equals("DonBest")){


        try {
            connectToCoral3();
            CachedRowSet res1 = con.selectQuery(
                    "select id,name,event_time from nodes where syst_id=16 and event_time>=now() order by event_time");

            //some debugging code
            while (res1.next()) {
                System.out.println("id= " + res1.getString("id") + " name= "
                        + res1.getString("name"));
            }

            while (res1.next()) {
                colours.add(res1.getString("id"));
                colours.add(res1.getString("name"));
                colours.add(res1.getString("event_time"));

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
     }else if(colour.equals("light")){
        colours.add("orange");
        colours.add("pink");
    }


    return (colours);
}
```

servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String c = request.getParameter("colour");
        ColourExpert ce = new ColourExpert();
        List<String> styles = ce.getColours(c);

    request.setAttribute("styles",styles);
    System.out.println(styles);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Retrieving rows failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/Home/simplePage.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
```

and here is my jsp,

```
<c:forEach items="${styles}" var="styles">
        <c:out value="${styles.id}" />
        <c:out value="${styles.name}" />
        <c:out value="${styles.event_time}" />
    </c:forEach>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">Error: ${error}</c:if>
```

any help would be great

Comment: Can you put the error you are getting, please?

Comment: That's the thing I am not getting any error its just not returning the results of my query.

Comment: Its normal because you have the code in a try/catch block... What i meant was to put the output of the line e.printStackTrace()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first `while` loop in your code. Then it will work.

```
//Remove This
while (res1.next()) {
    System.out.println("id= " + res1.getString("id") + " name= " + res1.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks was being really stupid also turns out i was trying to reference id which doesn't exists so it was giving me an error saying couldn't find id.

Answer (score 1):

First to access a request variable in JSTL you need to change your code to:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.styles}" var="styles">
    <c:out value="${styles.id}" />
    <c:out value="${styles.name}" />
    <c:out value="${styles.event_time}" />
</c:forEach>
<c:if test="${not empty error}">Error: ${error}</c:if>
```

Comment: here is my fix <div class="container">


  <c:forEach items="${styles}" var="styles">
   <c:out value="${styles}" />
   
  </c:forEach>
  <c:if test="${not empty error}">Error: ${error}</c:if>

 </div>